# Erro ao conectar php 5.5 com o SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Não consigo fazer funcionar uma simples conn entre o sql server e o php!!

já baixei e deixe na pasta ext os driver de acordo com minha versao do php

Já fiz referencia delas no php.ini reiniciei

e quando vou testar a conn da esse erro abaixo do codigo, alguem sabe como resolvo, inacreditavel que microsoft nao consiga fazer nada direito uma simples conexao ao banco deles enorme tormento.

```
  $servidor = "MEU\SQLSERVER";
  $basedatos = "novo";#
  $usuario = "novo";#
  $pass = "senha";

  $info = array('Database' => $basedatos);
  $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $info);


  if (!$conexion) {

    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

  }

echo 'Conectado';
```

erro:

```
  Array([0] => Array([0] => IMSSP[SQLSTATE] => IMSSP[1] => -49[code] => -49[2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11
        for SQL Server.Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11
        for SQL Server
        for x86: http: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado ) )
```

tentei outro codigo esse da locaweb esta dando outro erro

```
$tabela = "nometabela";    #Nome da tabela
$campo1 = "campo1tabela";  #Nome do campo da tabela
$campo2 = "campo2tabela";  #Nome de outro campo da tabela

$conninfo = array("Database" => $db, "UID" => $user, "PWD" => $password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($dbhost, $conninfo);

$instrucaoSQL = "SELECT $campo1, $campo2 FROM $tabela ORDER BY $campo1";

$params = array();
$options =array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

#ESSE DEU ERRO AQUI
$consulta = sqlsrv_query($conn, $instrucaoSQL, $params, $options);
$numRegistros = sqlsrv_num_rows($consulta);

echo "Esta tabela contém $numRegistros registros!\n<hr>\n";

if ($numRegistros!=0) {
    while ($cadaLinha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($consulta, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "$cadaLinha[$campo1] - $cadaLinha[$campo2]\n<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: O ODBC você tem instalado na maquina?

Comment: como vejo? estou usando o win 8 eu baixei as dll da ms e deixei na pasta ext e setei eles no php.ini estou usando xampp

Comment: Não é a extensão do php. você o SQL Server instalado na sua maquina? tenta baixar ele(driver odbc) aqui => http: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Comment: Pode ver, em painel de controle, ferramentas administrativas, fonte de dados ODBC

Comment: na verdade quero acessar um servidor remoto. 
meu odbc esta assim : aba dns de usuario: tem excel files e ms acesses db                    e na aba driver tem sqlserver + sql server native client 10 e 11

Comment: Blz, instala ai o odbc.

Answer (score 4):

1) Instale o pacote do ODBC driver 11.
   Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

2) Altere o código de conexão:

```
$servidor = "MEU\SQLSERVER";
$basedados = "novo";
$usuario = "novo";
$pass = "senha";

$conninfo = array("Database" => $basedados, "UID" => $usuario, "PWD" => $pass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $conninfo);
```

Recomendo você usar PDO.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Comment: rodou foi a falta do driver 
obrigado cara sou novo na empresa salvou meu pescoco ;)

Comment: Ótimo, se a minha resposta o ajudou marque-a como certa. ;)